Just created the neologism tag. Was it worth it?
When adding this question, I created the new neologism tag since none of the existing would fit for the case.
Comments and suggestions, as usual, are welcome.

Well, it is a tag without questions so it's going to be automatically eliminated in a while, but it does seem a reasonable tag

Just added the [tag:neologism] tag to some related questions.

I think it's a good addition. Well named tags are surely helpful in orienting through the site.
